# How to loop and get the specific value of the json object ,how can i use that json object to get the other entity present in that json object?

Tags: java, httpresponse

1. I am using java.
2. I have pasted below response for reference. I need to loop the below JSON Array response.
3. I can able to get the full response. But, I need to access the device Type first for example:deviceType=android and then using that device type I need to get the id of that particular device type for example: id=16.

> ```
> Response:
> {
>   "BannerConfigurations": [
>     {
>       "id": 16,
>       "partnerId": 69,
>       "appId": "28470216",
>       "affiliateData": "",
>       "status": true,
>       "deviceType": "ios",
>       "daysHidden": 15,
>       "daysReminder": 30
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 161,
>       "partnerId": 69,
>       "appId": "com.android.news",
>       "affiliateData": "",
>       "status": true,
>       "deviceType": "android",
>       "daysHidden": 15,
>       "daysReminder": 30
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Did you try using any JSON parsing library? Add the code you tried. You may find answers already there on Stackoverflow

Comment: Take a look at [this post][1], i think it may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503688/rest-and-json-converting-string-to-json-array

Comment: @YenneInfo - that possible duplicate is JavaScript, not Java. This one might be a better candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284194/easiest-way-to-extract-fields-from-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are starting with the full JSONObject but you can skip the first line if you've for the banner configurations array.

```
JSONObject data = [insert something following your structure above];
JSONArray bannerConfigurations = data.get("BannerConfigurations");
for (int i=0; i<bannerConfigurations.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject device = bannerConfigurations.getJSONObject(i);
    String deviceType = device.getString("deviceType");
    int id = device.getInt("id");
    // do stuff!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with your solution. Its works well.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a [Serialization Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Serialization_formats).  This means you should rarely analysis JSON directly.

The typical pattern would be to **deserialize** the JSON into Java objects and then use those in your analysis.  Maybe even using a object query API such as [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) on the resulting Collection for example.

Answer (score 0):

first create a class called `Devices` that contains setters and getters for all of the device attributes and a constructor "contract class"

then in your main class "Activity" define an instance:

```
static ArrayList<Devices> jsonDevice = new ArrayList<Devices>();
```

then in your `AsyncTask`-> `onPostExecute()` method write down this code:

```
try {
                jsonTicList.clear();
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jObject.getString("id");
                    String pid = jObject.getString("partnerId");
                    String adata = jObject.getString("affiliateData");
                    String status = jObject.getString("status");
                    String detype = jObject.getString("deviceType");
                    String datype = jObject.getString("daysHidden");
                    String darem = jObject.getString("daysReminder");
                    Devices tic = new Devices(id, pid,
                            adata,status,detype,datype,darem);
                    jsonDevice.add(tic);

                }

                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
            }
```

then loop around the data:

```
ArrayList<Devices> d = new ArrayList<Devices>(jsonDevice);
    for (Devices d1 : d) {
        if(!d1.getDeviceType().equals("Android")){
       //DO What ever you want 
         }}
```