# How to Loop through Json Array only until the id is equal to a certain number?

Tags: java, android

This is my Json, What I'm trying to do is get the thingsAboutTheVideo array if the musicVideo id = 303 or some other number

```
  {  
       musicVideos:[  
          {  
             id:303,
             youtubeVideoUrl:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvvcbcv",
             prettyVideoTitle:"Pretty Title",
             youtubeVideoTitle:"Crap Title",
             youtubeThumbnail:"https://image.com",
             thingsAboutTheVideo:[  
                {  
                   id:368,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:538,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:539,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:540,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                }
             ]
          },
          {  
             id:302,
             youtubeVideoUrl:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
             prettyVideoTitle:"Tcbcvbcv",
             youtubeVideoTitle:"xcvcx",
             youtubeThumbnail:"http://www.google.com/image",
             thingsAboutTheVideo:[  
                {  
                   id:64,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:535,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:536,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:537,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:541,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                },
                {  
                   id:542,
                   name:"Some Name",
                   facebook:"",
                   twitter:"",
                   instagram:"",
                   imdb:"",
                   website:"",
                   info:"",
                   image:"",
                   time:""
                }
             ]
          }
       }
```

This is what i have right now

```
for(int 1 = 0; i<jsonObject.length(); i++){
    JsonObject ob = jsonObject.getJsonObject(i);
    JSONArray aboutVideo = ob.getJsonArray("thingsAboutTheVideo");
    for(int j = 0 <aboutVideo.length(); j++){
        JsonObject objectTwo = aboutVideo.getJsonObject(j);
    }
}
```

Which Kind kind of works but when i try to get the second one it show nothing and the app crashes if I add while id == 303 if shows nothing at all not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You're asking why your code doesn't work, and to answer this well, we'll want to see more than a snippet and less than your whole code: consider creating and posting a [mcve] fully with your question. Please read the link to learn more about this useful tool.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757085/how-to-loop-and-get-the-specific-value-of-the-json-object-how-can-i-use-that-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the entry point for your for loop? What's `jsonObject.length()`? I suspect it starts within the first musicVideos array index. That would mean that you could only get the information of that one object. Anyway, from the ground up, hope it provides some insight (using org.json):

```
//content is a String containing the JSON Object you posted here (with an extra ]).    
JSONArray musicVideosArray = new JSONObject(content).getJSONArray("musicVideos"); //We are only interested in the array
for (int i = 0; i < musicVideosArray.length(); i++) { //For each object in the array
    JSONObject musicVideo  = musicVideosArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //You can already retrieve ID's here if that's all you're interested in:
    //int musicVideoID = musicVideo.getInt("id");
    //if (musicVideoID == 303) {//Do whatever}
    JSONArray aboutTheVideoArray = musicVideo.getJSONArray("thingsAboutTheVideo"); //Get the 'things' array containing ID's
    for (int j = 0; j < aboutTheVideoArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject aboutTheVideo = aboutTheVideoArray.getJSONObject(j);
        System.out.println("Object " + (j+1) + " of parent object "  + (i+1) + ", ID: " + aboutTheVideo.getInt("id"));
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

I would also like to note that the JSON Object you posted here isn't completely valid, you are missing a `]` character to close the `musicVideos` array.

[image]